# How can i open a .py file using if and open

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("wasans")
window.geometry('640x400')
window.resizable(False, False)

textbook = ['국어','영어','social']

textbookselecter = ttk.Combobox(window, text="교과서 선택", values=textbook)
textbookselecter.grid(column=0, row=0)
textbookselecter.place(x=140, y=200)
textbookselecter.set("목록 선택")

textbooksuntack = ttk.Label(window, width=11, borderwidth=2, background="#8182b8")
textbooksuntack.grid(column=0, row=0)
textbooksuntack.place(x=170, y=170)
textbooksuntack.anchor = CENTER

naeyong = textbookselecter.get()

if naeyong == "social":
    open("../social.py", "w")

window.mainloop()
```

How can I open a py file using if statement and open?

Also, please give your overall review of the code.

I am not good at English, so there may be awkward sentences using a translator. Please understand.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to check every time the `ttk.Combobox` is changed to check if `'social'` is generated.

`ttk.Combobox` raises a `"<<ComboboxSelected>>"` virtual event when selected.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("wasans")
window.geometry('640x400')
window.resizable(False, False)
def callback(eventObject):

    if textbookselecter.get() == "social":
        print("Opening File...")
        #file=open("...../social.py","r+")

textbook = ['국어','영어','social']

textbookselecter = ttk.Combobox(window, text="교과서 선택", values=textbook)
textbookselecter.grid(column=0, row=0)
textbookselecter.place(x=140, y=200)
textbookselecter.set("목록 선택")

textbooksuntack = ttk.Label(window, width=11, borderwidth=2, background="#8182b8")
textbooksuntack.grid(column=0, row=0)
textbooksuntack.place(x=170, y=170)
textbooksuntack.anchor = CENTER

textbookselecter.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",callback)

window.mainloop()
```